# Floating point exponentiation without power-function

Tags: math

Currently I have to work in an environment where the power-operator is bugged. Can anyone think of a method temporarily work around this bug and compute a^b (both floating point) without a power function or operator?

Comment: will 'b' always be an integer?  if so, just start with 1 and multiply it by a, b times

Comment: a and b are both floating point and will not be natural numbers

Comment: do you have sqrt() available?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

if you have sqrt() available:

```
double sqr( double x ) { return x * x; }
// meaning of 'precision': the returned answer should be base^x, where
//                         x is in [power-precision/2,power+precision/2]
double mypow( double base, double power, double precision )
{   
   if ( power < 0 ) return 1 / mypow( base, -power, precision );
   if ( power >= 10 ) return sqr( mypow( base, power/2, precision/2 ) );
   if ( power >= 1 ) return base * mypow( base, power-1, precision );
   if ( precision >= 1 ) return sqrt( base );
   return sqrt( mypow( base, power*2, precision*2 ) );
}
double mypow( double base, double power ) { return mypow( base, power, .000001 ); }
```

test code:

```
void main()
{
   cout.precision( 12 );
   cout << mypow( 2.7, 1.23456 ) << endl;
   cout << pow  ( 2.7, 1.23456 ) << endl;
   cout << mypow( 1.001, 1000.7 ) << endl;
   cout << pow  ( 1.001, 1000.7 ) << endl;
   cout << mypow( .3, -10.7 ) << endl;
   cout << pow  ( .3, -10.7 ) << endl;
   cout << mypow( 100000, .00001 ) << endl;
   cout << pow  ( 100000, .00001 ) << endl;
   cout << mypow( 100000, .0000001 ) << endl;
   cout << pow  ( 100000, .0000001 ) << endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
3.40835049344
3.40835206431
2.71882549461
2.71882549383
393371.348073
393371.212573
1.00011529225
1.00011513588
1.00000548981
1.00000115129
```

Comment: thanks alot. this is precisely was what i was looking for. Out of interest: can you give me any background to that algorithm?

Comment: Sure, the basic idea is that x^.5 = sqrt(x), x^.25 = sqrt(sqrt(x)), x^.125 = sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(x))), etc.  With these building blocks, we can say x^.625 = (x^.5)*(x^.125).  We can't express, say, x^.3 exactly, but we can get arbitrarily close.  I implemented this a little differently, but it uses the same concept.

Comment: Note that, if your sqrt function has the same restrictions as std::sqrt, then this won't work for negative bases.

Comment: I like your idea, but I guess it can be done in a better complexity in both time and space. The iterative version can save space up to O(1) and time can be improved up to O(log(n)).

Comment: Btw, you can implement sqrt as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3047531/8990391.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the identity *a*<sup>*b*</sup> = *e*<sup>(*b* log *a*)</sup>, then all the calculations are relative to the same base *e* = 2.71828...

Now you have to implement f(x) = ln(x), and g(x) = e^x.  The fast, low precision method would be to use lookup tables for f(x) and g(x).  Maybe that's good enough for your purposes.  If not, you can use the [Taylor series expansions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) to express ln(x) and e^x in terms
of multiplication and addition.

Comment: i have a working ln function. However, for the Taylor series I need powers again.

Comment: @ymihere: The Taylor series expansion only contains integer exponents, which can be reduced to multiplication.

Comment: @ymihere: do you have exp() available?  if so, this solution is best!

Comment: @tom: i don't have exp. actually, that's what I am working around.

Answer (score 3):

given that you can use sqrt, this simple recursive algorithm works:

Suppose that we're calculating aˆb. The way the algorithm works is by doing Fast Exponentiation on the exponent until we hit the fractional part, once in the fractional part, do a modified binary search, until we're close enough to the fractional part.

```
double EPS = 0.0001;

double exponentiation(double base, double exp){
  if(exp >= 1){
    double temp = exponentiation(base, exp / 2);
    return temp * temp;
  } else{
    double low = 0;
    double high = 1.0;

    double sqr = sqrt(base);
    double acc = sqr;    
    double mid = high / 2;

    while(abs(mid - exp) > EPS){
      sqr = sqrt(sqr);

      if (mid <= exp) {
          low = mid;
          acc *= sqr;
      } else{
          high = mid;
          acc *= (1/sqr);
      }

      mid = (low + high) / 2;
    }

    return acc;
  }
}
```