# Implement x^(e) in Extended Pascal, without using exponentiation operators

Tags: pascal, pow, exponentiation, exp

Part of a Pascal ISO 10206 program I am building, requires me to implement a function to exponentiate a real number (x) to Eulers number (e), without using any exponentiation functions already included in Pascal(**,pow,exp...).

I have been trying different algorithms for hours but I cant figure out how to do it without using the already included exponentiation functions.

Any help would be appreciated. Any mathematical algorithm of some sort etc... Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like rather a waste of time. Makes no sense not to use exp. In any case, there are algorithms published that you could find with some research. What research have you done?

Comment: Take a look at [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function). They can be used to calculate the `Exp()` of a value x (and a lot more). Just use a loop to increment, add or multiply the values in the series.

Comment: FWIW, you have a tag for Free Pascal, but you say you are using Extended Pascal. These are not the same. And are you looking for x^e or for e^x? The latter is the `Exp()` function, but the former can be calculated with it as well.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Not really. The convergence of the infinite sum is too slow to be useful.

Comment: @David: no one said it should be fast. I would use `Exp()` anyway, but if that is not allowed, Taylor series are one way to do this.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Only a fool with no mathematical knowledge would attempt to implement `Exp` on top of Taylor series.

Comment: @David: Like dentists. <g> Anyway, found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518973/floating-point-exponentiation-without-power-function. Looks like a nice trick, although I am not sure how good it is.

Comment: @Rudy There's no reason why a dentist shouldn't know maths. But this mathematician is telling you why Taylor series expansions are not practical for evaluating `Exp` generally.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  yes, I have searched for a lot of algorithms over the internet, but most of them end up having to use some kind of exponent. Ofcourse I know it can be easily done with exp(), but thats the point of the exercise, kind of rebuilding the exponential operators of pascal, which I cant seem to get done since most algorithms I found require me to use some kind of exponentiation. I will try what you guys proposed and post back.

Comment: What we proposed? I proposed nothing. I just pointed that Rudy's idea is not useful.

Comment: @David: what if you can divide them by a factor so that they are close to the center point (which is 0, I assume)? (and then adjust later on, of course). I don't have any programming language on this computer, but ISTM that that should work. FWIW, I know some maths, but such topics were not part of the curriculum for dentists. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Try and work out the details, then get back to me

Comment: Are you sure you mean `x^e` and not `e^x`? The latter is a _much_ more commonly used function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: finally got home and worked out the details. <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution pointed out by @RudyVelthuis in some other post, but modified it a bit. It is based upon that x^0.5 = sqrt(x), which we can use to our advantage. Ill leave the Pascal ISO 10206 code I used attached. Thank you all for your help, specially Rudy.

```
function MyPow(base,power,precision:real):real;
begin
    if (power<0) then MyPow:=1/MyPow(base,-power,precision)
    else   if (power>=10) then MyPow:=sqr(MyPow(base,power/2,precision/2))
    else   if (power>=1) then MyPow:=base*MyPow(base,power-1,precision)
    else   if (precision>=1) then MyPow:=sqrt(base)
    else MyPow:=sqrt(MyPow(base,power*2,precision*2));
end;
```

Comment: That's cool. But note that the solution I gave is slightly more accurate. In the original, I used Delphi's Extended (80-bit) type, which gave correct results all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it doesn't make sense *not* to use `Exp()` or a function based upon it. But if you really *must* use something else, and don't want to get too technical/mathematical, then the following should work (the real algorithm is far more complicated and requires much more knowledge of math).

The program uses a combination of the first N terms of Taylor series for the fraction of X and binary exponentiation for the integer part of X. It is probably not very fast, but pretty accurate, even for larger exponents. For comparison, I also display `Exp(X)`. If your Pascal has a `Double` or `Extended` type, use those instead of `Real`.

```
program SimplePower;

{ Required for Delphi, you can omit it in other Pascals: }
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{ Returns approximate value of e^X using sum of first N terms of Taylor series.
  Works fine with X values between 0 and 1.0 and N ~ 30. }
function Exponential(N: Integer; X: Real): Real;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1.0;
  for I := N - 1 downto 1 do
    Result := 1.0 + X * Result / I;
end;

{ Binary exponentiation of Base by integer Exponent. }
function IntegerExp(Base: Real; Exponent: Integer): Real;
begin
  Result := 1.0;
  while Exponent > 0 do
  begin
    if Odd(Exponent) then
      Result := Result * Base;
    Base := Base * Base;
    Exponent := Exponent shr 1;
  end;
end;

{ Combines IntegerExp function for integral part with 
  Exponential function for fractional part. }
function MyExp(N: Integer; X: Real): Real;
const
  E = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527; { from Google: "e euler" }
var
  Factor: Real;
  Fraction: Real;
begin
  Fraction := Exponential(N, Frac(X));
  Factor := IntegerExp(E, Trunc(X));
  Result := Factor * Fraction;
end;

{ Simple demo: }
const
  N = 30;
  X = 73.4567890242421234;

begin
  Writeln('MyExp(', N, ', ', X:22:18, ') = ', MyExp(N, X):22:18);
  Writeln('Exp(', X:22:18, ')       = ', Exp(X):22:18);
end.
```

Ref:

- [Taylor series for exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function)
- [Binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

I did not do anything for negative exponents, but just know that `Exp(-x) = 1/Exp(x)`. You could amend `MyExp`with that knowledge.

Comment: I see two downvotes. A comment about the "why" would be nice.