# Program to calculate square root c++

Tags: c++

I am making a C++ program to calculate the square root of a number. This program does not use the "sqrt" math built in operation. There are two variables, one for the number the user will enter and the other for the square root of that number. This program does not work really well and I am sure there is a better way to do so:

**Here is my full code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int squareroot = 0;
  int number;

  cout << "enter a number sp that i can calculate its squareroot" << endl;

  cin >> number;

  while (squareroot * squareroot != number){

      squareroot+=0.1;

}
cout << "the square root is" << squareroot << endl;
return 0;
 }
```

I know there must be a better way. Pls help. Looked through Google but don't understand the complex programs there as I am still a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not really a programming problem, but a math problem. There are several (efficient and less efficient) algorithms. First you should pick one and dive into it until you understand it in detail, then try to implement it.

Comment: To begin with, you need to know that uninitialized local variable (like your `squarertoot` variable) have an *indeterminate* value, and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*. Secondly, you declare `squareroot` as an *integer* variable, you can't add a floating-point value and expect it to work fine.

Comment: refer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611198/finding-square-root-without-using-sqrt-function

Comment: Sorry there, I had made a mistake, just edited squareroot = 1;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below explanation is given for the integer square root calculation:

> In number theory, the integer square root of a positive
>   integer n is the positive integer m which is the greatest integer less
>   than or equal to the square root of n

The approach your started is good but needs several correction to make it work:

1. you are working with `int` you want to add 1 to `squareroot` not 0.1
2. you want to stop your calculation when you `squareroot * squareroot` is equal or greater than `number`. Think about the case were the number is 26, you don't have an integer that multiplies itself to 26.
3. in the case of number equal to 26, do you want to return 5 or 6? After your `while` loop the value of `squareroot` will be 6 so you might want to reverse it to 5 (if `squareroot * squareroot` is different than `number`)

Below the exemple:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int squareroot = 0;
  int number;

  cout << "enter a number sp that i can calculate its squareroot" << endl;

  cin >> number;

  while (squareroot * squareroot < number){
      squareroot+=1;
  }

  if (squareroot * squareroot != number) --squareroot;

  cout << "the square root is" << squareroot << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Below a more efficient and elegant way of calculating the square root using binary search principle. O(log(n))

```
int mySqrt(int x) {
    if (x==0) return 0;
    int left = 1;
    int right = x/2 + 1;
    int res;

    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + ((right-left)/2);
        if (mid<=x/mid){
            left = mid+1;
            res=mid;
        }
        else {
            right=mid-1;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I believe that just giving the OP a solution is not really helping them. Maybe a better approach would be to point out why their code is not working and then point them in the right direction of how to change it?

Comment: But the result is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @user1095108 You are right the above explanation works only for the integer square root calculation

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Aryan.C You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped. Thanks

Comment: You can simply `return left - 1;`, without introducing `res` variable

Answer (score 2):

This function uses Nested Intervals (untested) and you can define the accuracy:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double mySqrt(double r) {
  double l=0, m;
  do {
     m = (l+r)/2;
     if (m*m<2) {
        l = m;
     } else {
        r = m;
     }
  } 
  while(fabs(m*m-2) > 1e-10);      
  return m;
}
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_intervals

Comment: I believe that just giving the OP a solution is not really helping them. Maybe a better approach would be to point out why their code is not working and then point them in the right direction of how to change it?

Comment: As written, this only outputs 1.41421,which is [sqrt(2)](https://oeis.org/A011547). It is almost a binary search, if you change `(m*m<2)` and `(m*m-2)` to not be stuck on `2` but instead use `r` and your original input for checking delta.

Answer (score 1):

This function will calculate the floor of square root if A is not a perfect square.This function basically uses binary search.Two things you know beforehand is that square root of a number will be less or equal to that number and it will be greater or equal to 1. So we can apply binary search in that range.Below is my implementation.Let me know if you don't understand anything in the code.Hope this helps.

```
int sqrt(int A) {
    if(A<1)return 0;
    if(A==1)return 1;

    unsigned long long start,end,mid,i,val,lval;
    start = 1;
    end = A;
    while(start<=end){
        mid = start+(end-start)/2;
        val = mid*mid;
        lval = (mid-1)*(mid-1);

        if(val == A)return mid;     
        else if(A>lval && A<val) return mid-1;
        else if(val > A)end = mid;
        else if(val < A)start = mid+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that just giving the OP a solution is not really helping them. Maybe a better approach would be to point out why their code is not working and then point them in the right direction of how to change it?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but question was asking for possible better way, that's why suggested better way.I think there is no harm in knowing different methods.Maybe I should not post the code just suggest the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, is that it only works if the square root of the number is exactly N*0.1, where N is an integer, meaning that if the answer is 1.4142 and not 1.400000000 exactly your code will fail. There are better ways , but they're all more complicated and use numerical analysis to approximate the answer, the easiest of which is the Newton-Raphson method.

you can use the function below, this function uses the Newton–Raphson method to find the root, if you need more information about the Newton–Raphson method, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) wikipedia article. and if you need better accuracy - but worse performance- you can decrease '0.001' to your likening,or increase it if you want better performance but less accuracy.

```
float mysqrt(float num)   {  
    float x = 1;

    while(abs(x*x - num) >= 0.001 )
        x = ((num/x) + x) / 2;

    return x;

}
```

if you don't want to import `math.h` you can write your own `abs()`:

```
float abs(float f) {
    if(f < 0)
        f = -1*f;
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Square Root of a number, given that the number is a perfect square.

The complexity is sqrt(n)

```
/**
 * Calculate square root if the given number is a perfect square.
 * 
 * Approach: Sum of n odd numbers is equals to the square root of n*n, given 
 * that n is a perfect square.
 *
 * @param number
 * @return squareRoot
 */
public static int calculateSquareRoot(int number) {
    
    int sum=1;
    int count =1;
    int squareRoot=1;
    while(sum<number) {
        count+=2;
        sum+=count;
        squareRoot++;
    }
    return squareRoot;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = 1, average, s, r;
    cout << "Squareroot a Number: ";
    cin >> s;
    r = s * 2;
    for ( ; ; ) //for ; ; ; is to run the code forever until it breaks
    {
        average = (x + s / x) / 2;
        if (x == average)
        {
            cout << "Answer is : " << average << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        x = average;
    }
}
```

You can try my code :D
the method that i used here is the Babylonian Squareroot Method
which you can find it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots