# finding square root of a number in C++

Tags: c++

```
//find square root of a number n till d decimal points
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main(){
   int n;int d;cin>>n>>d;
   double x=n;int i=1;
   while(i<=20){
       float t=(x+n/x)/2;i++;x=t;
   }
   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(d)<<x<<endl;



   }
```

The algorithm seems correct,but when I think setprecision rounds off my number which I don't want. Any other alternative to setprecision() which doesn't round off my final answer?
INPUT 
10  4
gives me 3.1623
however answer is 3.1622
Also input 10 7 gives me 3.1622777 which does have a 2 on 4 th decimal place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611198/finding-square-root-without-using-sqrt-function

Comment: The point of precision is to determine when t round: here, 3.1623 is closer to 3.1622777 than 3.1622, so it's not wrong to round it to 3. A good example is pi, mostly used as 3.1416 while more precision gives 3.1415926535... both are just as correct, simply more precise

Comment: I would try `double t = ...;` first.

Comment: @RSahu didn't work

Comment: @Adalcar  That's correct,but I still want answer as 3.1622, as answer is not getting passed by online judge

Comment: for std::setprecision see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20265447/104774)

Answer (score 2):

To truncate the value to d decimal places, multiply with 10^d, take floor, and then divide by the same number.

```
double multiplier = pow(10, d);
double result = floor(t * multiplier) / multiplier;
cout << fixed << setprecision(d) << result << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks,but isn't there just a one statement function for giving my answer without rounding off?

Comment: There might be. You'd have to search. This is the best I could come up with.