# python convert 2d array to 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and need to do the following thing:

I've given an 1d array of vectors (so pretty much 2d).

My task is to create an 1d array that contains the length of each vector.

```
array([[0.  , 0.  ],
   [1.  , 0.  ],
   [1.  , 1.  ],
   [1.  , 0.75],
   [0.75, 1.  ],
   [0.5 , 1.  ]
   ...
```

should be converted to

```
array([0,
   1,
   1.4142,
   ...
```

I could easily do this in theory but I am not familiar with the inbuild commands of python and I am very happy if someone could tell me some inbuild commands of python that can do this.

Comment: What do you mean by length of each vector? How does `[1,1]` turn into `1.4142`?

Comment: well the length of the vector (1,1)^T is sqrt(2) = 1.4142 (mathematically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NumPy you can use vectorised operations:

```
A = np.array([[0.  , 0.  ],
              [1.  , 0.  ],
              [1.  , 1.  ],
              [1.  , 0.75],
              [0.75, 1.  ],
              [0.5 , 1.  ]])

res = np.sqrt(np.square(A).sum(1))

array([ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.25      ,  1.25      ,
        1.11803399])
```

Alternatively, if you prefer a less functional solution:

```
res = (A**2).sum(1)**0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

Using norm from [np.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0., 0.],
              [1., 0.],
              [1., 1.],
              [1., 0.75],
              [0.75, 1.],
              [0.5, 1.]])

print(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
[0.         1.         1.41421356 1.25       1.25       1.11803399]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list comprehension. In Python 2,

```
print [(x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1])**0.5 for x in arr]
```

where `arr` is your input

Comment: This looks like it just flattens the array. The OP doesn't want to simply flatten the array. He effectively wants to find the magnitude of each vector.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem at first. You can refresh my answer.

Comment: thank you. That works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import math
b = []
for el in arr:
    b.append(math.sqrt(el[0]**2 + el[1]**2))

print b
```

or you can do it even shorter:

```
b = [math.sqrt(el[0]**2 + el[1]**2) for el in arr]
```

where `arr` is the your array.

Here is and one more example with `lambda`:

```
b = map(lambda el: (el[0]**2 + el[1]**2)**0.5, arr)
```

Comment: thank you that works :) forgot about the "ugly" append method in python...

Comment: @FinnEggers, You can do this and without `append`. See my second example.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over your array to find the vector length:

```
array=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
empty=[]
for (x,y) in array:
    empty.append((x**2+y**2)**0.5)
print(empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with hypotenuse [`np.hypot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html)

```
np.hypot(array[:, 0], array[:, 1])
```

Comment: does this also work for higher dimensional vectors?

Comment: No, it works just for 2d vectors. See Daniel Mesejo's or jpp's answer for n-dimensional approach.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that. I am using math.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(el))) now :)

Comment: @FinnEggers, as a side note, you can actually use `expr**0.5` instead of `math.sqrt(expr)`

Comment: I assume it is not as efficient?

Comment: You can see it compared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327002/which-is-faster-in-python-x-5-or-math-sqrtx)