# Why is math.sqrt massively slower than exponentiation?

Tags: python, performance, macos-catalina, python-3.8

I can't believe what I just measured:

```
python3 -m timeit -s "from math import sqrt" "sqrt(2)"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 42.8 nsec per loop

python3 -m timeit "2 ** 0.5"
50000000 loops, best of 5: 4.93 nsec per loop
```

This goes against any intuition... it shoud be exactly the opposite!

Python 3.8.3 on macOS Catalina

Comment: The first code has the overhead of doing an `import`, and the second doesn't.

Comment: @JohnGordon The import is in the setup statement, which should not be timed.

Comment: Repeating what @John Gordon just said, "[In these micro-benchmarks, math.sqrt will be slower, because of the slight time it takes to lookup the sqrt in the math namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/327024/8286364)"

Comment: @AdamBoinet `sqrt` has already been looked up in the setup.

Answer (score 81):

Python 3 is precomputing the value of `2 ** 0.5` at compile time, since both operands are known at that time. The value of `sqrt`, however, is *not* known at compile time, so the computation necessarily occurs at run time.

You aren't timing how long it takes to compute `2 ** 0.5`, but just the time it takes to load a constant.

A fairer comparison would be

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import sqrt" "sqrt(2)"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 50.7 nsec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "x = 2" "x**0.5"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 56.7 nsec per loop
```

---

I'm not sure if there is a way to show unoptimized byte code. Python starts by parsing source code into an abstract syntax tree (AST):

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("2**0.5"))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=2), op=Pow(), right=Num(n=0.5)))])'
```

**Update**: This particular optimization is now applied [directly to the abstract syntax tree](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Python/ast_opt.c#L214), so the byte code is generated directly from something like

```
Module(body=Num(n= 1.4142135623730951))
```

The `ast` module doesn't appear to apply the optimization.

<strike>The compiler takes the AST and generates unoptimized byte code; in this case, I *believe* it would look (based on the output of `dis.dis("2**x")` and `dis.dis("x**0.5")`) like</strike>

```
LOAD_CONST       0  (2)
LOAD_CONST       1  (0.5)
BINARY_POWER
RETURN_VALUE
```

The raw byte code is then subject to modification by the peephole optimzizer, which can reduce these 4 instructions to 2, as shown by the `dis` module.

The compiler then generates byte code from the AST.

```
>>> dis.dis("2**0.5")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1.4142135623730951)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

[While the following paragraph was originally written with the idea of optimizing byte code in mind, the reasoning applies to optimizing the AST as well.]

Since nothing at runtime affects how the two `LOAD_CONST` and following `BINARY_POWER` instruction are evaluated (for example, there are no name lookups), the peephole optimizer can take this sequence of byte codes, perform the computation of `2**0.5` itself, and replace the first three instructions with a single `LOAD_CONST` instruction that loads the result immediately.

Comment: Yep! Makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: This optimization actually happens at AST level in recent Python versions (see [`Python/ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Python/ast_opt.c)), so "unoptimized" bytecode isn't actually generated any more.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'd seen references to doing optimizations at at the AST level, but thought it was a future enhancement since the `ast` module doesn't (yet) take advantage of it.

Answer (score 25):

To enhance [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431424), here's a proof:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('2 ** 0.5')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (1.4142135623730951)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

vs.

```
>>> dis.dis('sqrt(2)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (sqrt)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> dis.dis('44442.3123 ** 0.5')
          0 LOAD_CONST               0 (210.81345379268373)
          2 RETURN_VALUE
```

I do not believe, that `44442.3123 ** 0.5` is precomputed at compile time. We should better check the AST of code.

```
>>> import ast
>>> import math
>>> code = ast.parse("2**2")
>>> ast.dump(code)
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=2), op=Pow(), right=Num(n=2)))])'
>>> code = ast.parse("math.sqrt(3)")
>>> ast.dump(code)
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Attribute(value=Name(id='math', ctx=Load()), attr='sqrt', ctx=Load()), args=[Num(n=3)], keywords=[]))])"
```

Comment: `ast.parse` simply doesn't perform the peephole optimization. (I believe the optimizer uses the byte code generated from the parse tree as its input.)

Comment: @chepner You are right. I been wondering why it is compiled to load const. And Your updated answer clearly explains that. Thanks for update.